# Commutative diagrams of sets and functions

Tags: functions

Consider these two diagrams of sets and functions (with $f$ and $f'$ invertible):

\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 A & \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} & B  && &B & \overset{f^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} & A\\
 u\downarrow&  & v\downarrow & &; & v\downarrow &  & u\downarrow\\
 A' & \overset{f'}{\longrightarrow} & B' &  && B' & \overset{f'^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} & A'
\end{array}

Can I say that the first commutes if and only if the second does? In other words, is it true that

$$v\circ f=f'\circ u \textrm{ if and only if } u\circ f^{-1}=f'^{-1}\circ v$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. $v\circ f =f' \circ u\Rightarrow f'^{-1}\circ v= f'^{-1}\circ v \circ f\circ f^{-1}=f'^{-1}\circ f'\circ u \circ f^{-1}=u\circ f^{-1}$